# How do I wait for a promise in loop to finish before do some other stuff?

Tags: node.js, promise

I still confused about how to use promises. I have a for loop call an asynchronous method which returns a value. I use this value to push into an array. But when I print the array it is empty. Here is what I did:

```
async function getLink(link) {
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(LINK)
    const result = await page.evaluate( async() => {
        let data = [];
        const $ = window.$;
        $('#gallery_01 .item').each(function(index, product) {
            data.push($(product).find('a').attr('data-image'));
        });
        return data;
    });
    await browser.close();
    return result;
}
var final = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var data = getLink(value[i].url).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // urls show here
            final.push(data);
        });
}
Promise.all(final).then(() => {
        console.log(final) // empty
})
```

The `final` show empty. What did I do wrong with Promise? Pls help!

Comment: is the page.goto() function supposed to take the link parameter instead of LINK?  where is LINK defined?

Comment: it is `const` parameter. It work fine when I show the `data`. Please see the edit

Comment: Please be careful using Promise.all because it immediately (but always asynchronously) rejects when a single promise rejects with its rejected value. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what `value` is, but it looks like it's supposed to be an array of objects with a `url` property?

Assuming the getLink() function is okay, try this for your loop:

```
const final = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  final.push(getLink(value[i].url));
}

Promise.all(final)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Or a slightly more compact way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
const promises = value.map(v => getLink(v.url));

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: @tuanptit Use Promise.all() carefully, it would throw an error at first instance a promise is rejected, and won't process the rest of promises.

Answer (score 1):

Update: My bad, got a bit confused. The following code would only work without `() =>` after the `var fn`

You are very close. Try this:

```
var final = [];
var results = []; // you need a separate array for results
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       // renamed the variable, changed 'data' to 'fn' 
        var fn = () => getLink(value[i].url).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // urls show here
            results.push(data); 
        });
        final.push(fn);
}
Promise.all(final).then(() => {
        console.log(results) 
})
```

Promise.all accepts an array of promises. You have an array 'final' but seem to try to store the result of the fucntion execution as well as the function itself.

To do this correctly - first get an array of promises. Then pass them to Promise.all().

P.S. Assuming your function actually works, haven't looked at it, since the question was about promises.

Comment: You are pushing functions into the array not a promise.

Comment: Still return empty

Comment: I assumed the function returns a promise, because the function if async

Comment: The function might return a promise, but not if you don't call it. In your code `final` just contains a bunch of references to the function `fn`

Comment: Promise.all(final) actually executes the promises in the array

Comment: @AndriiRudavko there are no promises in the array only functions. You should code this and run it *it doesn't work*. `Promise.all()` does not automatically call function references.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You are correct. Thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate it)